# Synchronous JSONP request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, synchronous

There are many questions out there about JSONP requests and the fact that they cannot be made synchronously. Most workarounds involve using the callbacks, or the success function in an ajax request to do what you want, but I don't think that's going to work for me.

Background: I'm working on a search application using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). I'm developing a javascript API for others to use to interact with Solr so they don't need to understand the ins and outs of a Solr search request.

In my api, I have a Request object, with a function called doRequest. The purpose of the function is to perform the call to the solr server (on another domain, thus the need for JSONP), and return a Response object.

```
Request.prototype.doRequest = function (){
var res = new Response();
$.ajax({
    url: this.baseURL,
    data: 'q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json', 
    success: function(data){
        res.response = data.response;
        res.responseHeader = data.responseHeader;
        /*
          other...
          stuff...
        */
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf'
});
res.request = this;
return res;
};
```

The "user" would use this function like so...

```
var req = new Request();
var res = req.doRequest();
```

and then do something or other with the results in res.

Given that I cannot do a synchronous JSONP request, and I cannot return from within the ajax function, I can't figure out anyway to make sure res is fully populated for the user before they start using it.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to protect your users from having to write a callback function? So much of Javascript requires understanding how to do things asynchronously, you can only shield newbies from that for so long...

Comment: Asynchrony is infectious.  Once one part of your control flow uses a callback, so will the rest of your control flow. I am afraid there is no way around this. One of the joys and horrors of Javascript.

Comment: Actually there is a way around it, but it requires a compilation step: https://npmjs.org/package/streamline

Comment: @MattB., I'm trying to avoid the problem Andrew mentioned. Once you're in a callback you have to basically stick in it forever.

Comment: @CTC I realize that it's slightly less straightforward using callbacks (although I still think it's easy enough to learn). But the only alternative, however you would manage to make the call synchronous, is to block the interface while the request is being made, which is bad for user experience. That's why I think even doing synchronous AJAX requests as jQuery allows is a bad idea.

Comment: Since it may be of academic interest, you could probably use a `while (true)` loop in conjunction with `setInterval` to force it to be synchronous, but I do NOT recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using callback functions is the way to do this. Here's how I ended up doing it in case you're interested.

```
Request.prototype.doRequest = function (callback){
var res = new Response();
$.ajax({
    url: this.baseURL,
    data: 'q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json', 
    success: function(data){
        res.response = data.response;
        res.responseHeader = data.responseHeader;
        res.request = this;
        /*
          other...
          stuff...
        */
        callback(res);
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf'
});
};
```

And now the user uses the function like so:

```
var req = new Request();
var res = req.doRequest(parseResults);
```

Where parseResults is the callback function defined by the user that takes the response object as a parameters.

```
function parseResults(res){
    //Doing work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the rest of your program is synchronous, there are times when you need to touch a REST interface synchronously. An example is where you have a request to get an array of assets (perhaps asset Ids) and then hydrate each of the Ids to get the full data/asset. If you've used the Ooyala API then you know what I mean.

I created what seems to be the first synchronous JSONP module to allow each next request to only run once its previous request has finished. It uses recursion instead of Promises, which means the next request will not be sent until the previous one is successful. The API lives here: https://github.com/cScarlson/jsonpsync

Hope this helps.